# Insert SQL (Access) not working using webmethods Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, web-services, insert, webmethod

I am trying to insert some fields into the local ms access database using webmethod(services) and website. I have tried looking up but cannot seem to spot where I've gone wrong. Can anyone tell me if I am doing it right. The code below does not add new data into the database nor does it direct me back to the page requested.

Services Webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public void AddNewPosts(string postUserName, string postTitle, DateTime postMessagepostDateTime, int subTopicId, string postMessage)
{
    //Connection string for the datbase
    string database = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/Forum.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";
    OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(database);

    //Execute the query
    string queryStr = "Insert into Posts (TopicId, PostTitle, PostUserName, PostDateTime) VALUES (" + subTopicId + ",'" + postTitle + "','" + postUserName + "'," + postMessagepostDateTime + ")";

    // Create a command object 
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(queryStr, myConn);
    // Open the connection 
    myCommand.Connection.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myCommand.Connection.Close();
}
```

Calling the above method from my website:

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //string postUserName = Page.User.Identity.Name;
    string postUserName = "tom123";
    string postTitle = txtTitle.Text;
    string postMessage = txtMessage.Text;
    DateTime postDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    int subTopicId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);

    Service fs = new Service();
    fs.AddNewPosts(postUserName, postTitle, postDateTime, subTopicId, postMessage);

    //Redirect back to the SubTopic page
    Response.Redirect("SubTopic.aspx?id=" + subTopicId.ToString());


}
```

Comment: are you saying there is no error message? without knowing more maybe make sure the id you are trying to insert is not already in your table.

Comment: also you should see what the return value from ExecuteNonQuery() is : int returnVal = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: @Constanta The ID I am passing can be used multiple times, this determines which topic does the post needs to be inserted in. There is a post ID which is unique and it's no affecting that column. And yes, there are no error message at all. It just doesnt do anything when the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with quotes around the date time
string queryStr = "Insert into Posts (TopicId, PostTitle, PostUserName, PostDateTime) VALUES (" + subTopicId + ",'" + postTitle + "','" + postUserName + "','" + postMessagepostDateTime + "')";